# Web Controls vs StringBuilder

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms, stringbuilder, web-controls

I'm currently looking over an ASP.NET WebForms application where one of the web forms displays a HTML table, which is built up entirely by a `StringBuilder` object in the code-behind and then set as the `InnerHtml` of a `div` element.

I'm looking at converting this into using Web Controls (most likely a [`Repeater`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx)) so that there is better front-end visibility as to what is being rendered.

Are there any performance advantages from using Web Controls over pure code-behind logic? Or does this all equate to the same for the rendering engine?

Comment: I think it is more of code maintenance but not performance related. StringBuilder can be used for dynamic messages like status, etc. Oh yes, webcontrols have viewstate but if it is not required in your case, consider disabling it.

Comment: Repeater are nice since it will build the html for you however it is slower then a stringbuilder. For me i use repeater is cleaner i would use it for internal pages or pages that wont get viewed my many people. if it is a heavy traffic page i would use a stringbuilder since it is faster however it does have it's draw backs. for example it can get mess in the code behind when you are adding html. On another not i would use a string builder with a literalcontrol rather then a div. StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder; sb.Append("<div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>"); litControl.text = sb.toString();

Answer (score 2):

To answer the specific question, use of `StringBuilder` has better performance than using a server control, such as a repeater.

However from a support point of view you would be better to stick with something that makes it very obvious to you, and any other person that may come along later to support your code, what it is the page is doing.

On those occasions where performance is the main factor I use a `StringBuilder` over controls every time.

As with any performance related question/answer, you should test and adapt your code as required.  Don't try and include performance enhancements when they are not required; in most cases code that is written for performance is more difficult to support.